# how to display sequentially overlapping JLabels

Tags: java, swing, japplet

This must be a kind of elevator. If I click a button ( on the left or on the right side of the GUI ) the rectangle must move floor by floor with a certain delay. My problem is that my GUI simply refuse to display sequentially; instead, it display all the "floors" in the same time. :(

```
//this is the applet
import javax.swing.JApplet;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class applet extends JApplet{
    public applet(){
        add(new elevator());
    }}
//this is the main class
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class elevator extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private JButton[] externalButtons=new JButton[11];
    private JButton[] internalButtons=new JButton[13];
    private JLabel[] floors=new JLabel[11];
    private JLabel o1=new JLabel();
    private JLabel o2=new JLabel();
    private JPanel p1=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p2=new JPanel();
    private JPanel p3=new JPanel();
    private JLabel[] labelBlueLeft=new JLabel[11];
    private JLabel[] labelBlueRight=new JLabel[11];
    private JLabel[] labelRedLeft=new JLabel[11];
    private JLabel[] labelRedRight=new JLabel[11];
    private int firstOption=0, lastOption;

    public elevator(){
        repaint();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(11,1));
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(11,1));
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(15,1));

        for(int i=1; i<11;i++){
            externalButtons[i]=new JButton("Floor " + i);
            externalButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        externalButtons[0]=new JButton("Ground");
        externalButtons[0].addActionListener(this);
        for(int i=3; i<13; i++){
            internalButtons[i]=new JButton("Floor " + (i-2));
            internalButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        internalButtons[0]=new JButton("Alarm!");
        internalButtons[1]=new JButton("Stop");
        internalButtons[2]=new JButton("Ground");
        internalButtons[0].addActionListener(this);
        internalButtons[1].addActionListener(this);
        internalButtons[2].addActionListener(this);

        for(int i=0; i<11;i++){
            floors[i]=new JLabel("");
            floors[i].setLayout( new GridLayout());
            floors[i].setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(150,150,150)));
            floors[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,25));
            if((i%2)==0) {
                floors[i].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                floors[i].setOpaque(true);
            }
            labelBlueLeft[i]=new CustomLabel(25,0,35,25,0,0);
            labelBlueRight[i]=new CustomLabel(25,0,35,25,0,1);
            labelRedLeft[i]=new CustomLabel(25,0,35,25,1,0);
            labelRedRight[i]=new CustomLabel(25,0,35,25,1,1);
            }       
        floors[firstOption].add(labelBlueLeft[0]);

        for(int i=10; i>-1; i--){
            p1.add(externalButtons[i]);
            p2.add(floors[i]);
        }
        p3.add(o1); p3.add(o2);
    for(int i=12; i>-1; i--)
        p3.add(internalButtons[i]);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
        //ACTION PERFORMED

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
                if(e.getSource()==externalButtons[i]) lastOption=i;
            }
            for(int i=2; i<13; i++){
                if(e.getSource()==internalButtons[i]) lastOption=i-2;
            }               
            floors[firstOption].remove(labelBlueLeft[0]);



            if(firstOption<lastOption){ 
                    for(int i=firstOption; i<lastOption+1; i++){                             
                        floors[i].add(labelRedLeft[i]);
                        floors[i].validate();   
                        floors[i].repaint();
                    }
                }
            else if(firstOption>lastOption){
                    for(int i=firstOption; i>lastOption-1; i--){
                        floors[i].add(labelRedLeft[i]);
                        floors[i].revalidate();                 
                        floors[i].repaint();
                    }}
                firstOption=lastOption;                 
        }       
    }

//this is my CustomLabel class
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CustomLabel extends JLabel{
    private int x=25, y=0, width=35, height=20; 
    public CustomLabel(int x1, int y1, int width1, int height1, int clr, int ind){
        if(ind==1){x1=150; y1=0;}
        if(clr==1)
            {setForeground(Color.red);}
        else
            {setForeground(Color.blue);}
        x=x1; y=y1;
        width=width1;
        height=height1;
    }   
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        repaint();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `repaint` within a `paint` method, this is setting you up for an infinite loop of paint requests that will consume your CPU cycles

Comment: You never remove `labelRedLeft[i]`...

Comment: I think you need to change the way you are thinking about the problem.  Create a "Floor" class (extending from `JPanel`), add a series of `JPanel`s or `JLabel`s to it, indicating the number of available elevators.  This, then, becomes a states display.  Create an elevator pool, this contains a list of "virtual" elevators, which determines their current floor and target floor, if any.  You can then use this pool to schedule requests (find the most likely elevator that could meet the request) and update the state of the elevators (via some kind of timer)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for suggestion! After I changed the plan I found another problem: how to pick up my "virtual elevators" from the pool! :))
I tried GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints, then JTabbedPane... Finally CardLayout really worked! I transformed my elevators in images and here I am: I have a functional elevator! Thanks again! ;)